# Calculate zodiac from date and time

Tags: algorithm, date, astronomy

I am looking for an algorithm that calculates the zodiac sign from a given date and time.
A simple lookup table is not accurate enough. There are some websites out there that offer such calculations but I was unable to find a specific algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried to write any code yet? AFAIK, it's all [date ranges](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Zodiac.java.html)

Comment: *not accurate enough*: I was not aware that Zodiac stuff [was accurate](http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/starfinder2/en/) anyway.

Comment: Astronomy? Really?

Comment: @n.m. yes, it has to do with the suns apparent position. so astronomy it is.

Comment: @cricket_007 it's not just ranges. The start and end of zodiacs vary each year.